# Sort object by key whilst retaining present values to match order of array

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two objects. One in is in the format `(footerMenuOptions)`:

```
[{Home: true}, {About: false}, {Features: false}, {Contact: false}]
```

The second is in the format `(this.navbarMenuOptions)`:

```
["Home", "About", "Features", "Contact"]
```

---

At times, the order of the second object `(this.navbarMenuOptions)` will change, to lets say:

```
["About", "Home", "Features", "Contact"]
```

I want the first objects order  `(footerMenuOptions)` to change to be able to reflect this (i.e. the keys), but the values to remain intact).

In the case where the key-value pair does not exist, it should just be created with a default value of false (i.e. if `this.navbarMenuOptions` has a new entry).

What would be the most performant way of accomplishing this:

Code is as follows:

```
toggleFooterMenuOptionVisibility(index: number) {
   // Some other stuff happens beforehand which isn't important
   footerMenuOptions = this.sortFooterMenuOptions(footerMenuOptions);
}

sortFooterMenuOptions(footerMenuOptions) {
   // this.navbarMenuOptions is a global variable so it doesn't need to be passed in
   return footerMenuOptions;
}
```

Comment: Your `footerMenuOptions` is supposed to be an Object. Something like this: `{ Home: true, About: false, Features: false, Contact: false }` and `this.navbarMenuOptions` is a string array. Since `footerMenuOptions` is an Object, the sequence of keys won't really make much sense in there. I'm not able to understand what exactly you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: I want to sort the sequence of the keys in `footerMenuOptions` so that it matches `this.navbarMenuOptions`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your main object's keys and get indexes from second array and sort your object's keys by these indexes like below:

```js
var arr1 = {
  Home: true,
  About: false,
  Features: false,
  Contact: false
}



var arr2 = ["About", "Home", "Features", "Contact"];
const ordered = {};
Object.keys(arr1).sort((a, b) => {
  return arr2.indexOf(a) - arr2.indexOf(b);
}).forEach(r => ordered[r] = arr1[r]);

console.log(ordered);
```

I assumed your object has 1 key or the first key is the same with values in the second array.
So if we apply it to your example it should become like this :

```js
sortFooterMenuOptions(unsortedFooterMenuOptions) {
  const sortedFooterMenuOptions = {};
  Object.keys(unsortedFooterMenuOptions)
    .sort((a, b) => {
      return this.navbarMenuOptions.indexOf(a) - this.navbarMenuOptions.indexOf(b);
    }).forEach(r => sortedFooterMenuOptions[r] = unsortedFooterMenuOptions[r]);
  return sortedFooterMenuOptions;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried the following: https://pastebin.com/ZAtU804u. I get the error: `ERROR TypeError: unsortedFooterMenuOptions.sort is not a function`. Any idea on how I can fix this?

Comment: @methuselah you should return a value inside sort function. `return this.navbarMenuOptions.indexOf(k1) - this.navbarMenuOptions.indexOf(k2);` It will mutate the original array you don't need to assign it.

Comment: Thanks, I am seeing another issue however. Please check https://pastebin.com/DmEY9DKp. I get the error `Error:(310, 25) TS2339: Property 'sort' does not exist on type 'Object'.`. I think it is because my object exists as `[{Home: true, About: false, Features: false, Contact: false}]` and not as above `[{Home: true}, {About: false}, {Features: false}, {Contact: false}]`. How can I fix this?

Comment: @methuselah so  you array have only 1 object? Which has the keys `Home` `About` etc. Or it is not even an array according to the  error. Please note that  `[]` is array notation and `{}` is object notation.

Comment: `footerMenuOptions` only has one object, in the format `[{Home: true, About: false, Features: false, Contact: false}]`.

Comment: @methuselah i updated my answer and i don't think its an array. Cause the exception tells the opposite : `Property 'sort' does not exist on type 'Object'`